# My data only shows if I debug it. What's going on?

Tags: debugging, stripe-payments, cakephp-3.0

I'm working with Stripe's API and am trying to retrieve data. I have the code below:

```js
$data = \Stripe_Invoice::all(array(
"customer" => $user->customer_id
));
```

If I set the AJAX response equal to $data, the response is shown as empty ( {} ). If I debug it in the backend, I get a huge list of all kinds of awesome properties to use. All I do is this:

```js
debug($data); // returns huge data set
```

The trouble is that I can't access the variable in the frontend. I want to use:

```js
console.log(response);
html += response.url;
```

And things to that effect, but the data is completely empty when the front end interprets it, for some reason.

In the same effect, I can't set it as a session either (I used to set session logs to debug instead of using the debug feature).

```js
$data // can be accessed on the frontend if we use just php to set a variable
$_SESSION['log'] = $data; // empty
```

What's going on? I'm using the PHP framework CakePHP 3 (latest version of Beta). I think it has something to do with returning the data as serialized (maybe?) but that wouldn't explain the session logging. This happens right before we send the data back:

```js
    $this->set(compact('data', $data));
    $this->set('_serialize', 'data');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was that the values could not be displayed while the array was protected. Calling Stripe's method __toArray() on the Stripe object made the data accessible, and setting worked past this point.

```
$data = \Stripe_Invoice::all(array(
    "customer" => $user->customer_id
));

$data = $data->__toArray();

$this->set(compact('data', $data));
$this->set('_serialize', 'data');
```

Answer (score 0):

If $data is not empty than you should just use the set method in the controller

```
 $this->set(compact('data', $data));
```

Than you should have the corresponding view at /src/Template/ControllerName/json/methodName.ctp (Change ControllerName and methodName to what you have)

This file should be this.

```
<?php
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

That is all. You should have your data on your client side as a json object.